# ¿error cadena tipo string?

Tags: c++, c

Tengo el siguiente error en mi código y no se porque no me funciona, tengo un archivo que tiene un numero de registros y tengo que guardar los dos primeros valores como variables pero no me aparece de forma correcta

[image: base de datos]

Y este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
    
int main(){
        
      char nombreArchivoEnt[] = "IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.csv";
      int n = contar_registros(nombreArchivoEnt);
      cout<<n<<endl;
    
      FILE *pEnt = fopen(nombreArchivoEnt,"r");
      if(pEnt==NULL){
            printf("Problema al abrir el archivo %s. Termina el programa.\n",nombreArchivoEnt);
            exit(-1);
      }
    
      char linea[1000];
      fgets(linea,sizeof(linea),pEnt);
      linea[strlen(linea)-1] = '\0';
      cout<<linea<<endl;
    
      char numero1[100];
      char numero2[100];
      
      int32_t j = 0;
      int32_t i = 0;
      
      int resultado1 = 0;
      int resultado2 = 0;
    //aqui se guarda el fragmento de la variable tipo string a variable
      while(linea[i] != ','){
    
            numero1[j++] = linea[i++];
            numero1[j] = '\0';
            resultado1 = atoi(numero1);
            i++;
      } 

      j = 0;
    
      while(linea[i] != ','){
    
            numero2[j++] = linea[i++];
            numero2[j] = '\0';
            resultado2 = atoi(numero2);
            i++;
    
      }

      cout<<"el primer valor es:"<<resultado1<<endl;
      cout<<"el segundo valor es:"<<resultado2<<endl;
      cout<<"valor de la variable i es:"<<i<<endl;
        
      return 0;
}
```

Pero me aparece los siguiente,en el primer valor debería aparecerme 15 como numérico y en el siguiente 16777215
[image: compilacion]

Comment: Te recomiendo verificar que tu archivo IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.csv no tenga saltos de linea donde no debería, espacios de mas, y que el final no sea un salto de linea.

Comment: @es un archivo csv,tiene saltos de linea

Answer (score 0):

Defines variables de tipo *char*. Cuando deberian estar en tipo entero.
Luego, a la variable resultado, le asignas el valor en *char* por estar antes definidas de esa manera.

```
 char numero1[100];
 char numero2[100];
```

Creo que en esa parte del codigo se encuentra lo que pides. Saludos.